# Dart how to filter array by string

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple array like this

```
[{ID: 1195, SubCategoryID: 87, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}, {ID: 1192, SubCategoryID: 87, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}, {ID: 1191, SubCategoryID: 87, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}]
```

And I have simple ID `1195` like this

now I need to filter the array which has ID 1195

I try something like this

```
 var filterData =  searchArray.searchArrayData.where((i) => i.ID == snapshot.data[i].ID).toList();
```

Its showing error  `Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'ID'.`

also try like this

```
var filterData =  searchArray.searchArrayData.where((i) => i['ID'] == snapshot.data[i].ID).toList();
```

Its showing this error `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [
  {ID: 1195, SubCategoryID: 87, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)},
  {ID: 1192, SubCategoryID: 87, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)},
  {ID: 1191, SubCategoryID: 87, Name: Fajita Pizza (S)}
];

var filterData = items.where((element) => element["ID"] == 1195);
```

Comment: `map` is for "mapping", not for "filtering" elements from a list - you should use `where` instead

Comment: ok, I edit my answer thanks for mentioning @pskink

Comment: its showing this error when i run A value of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are using `snapshot.data[i].ID`: you are passing as an index of the array (that should be an int) a map (`i`).
If you clarify what snapshot.data is returning I can suggest you a proper way to do it.